# Show memory and cpu in C

Tags: c, openbsd

how can I see my CPU mhz and Free mem (like free) in OpenBSD with a C code?

Answer (score 3):

Using BSD sysctl(3) to get the live CPU frequency and posix sysconf(3) for free.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

main (argc, argv)
        char **argv;
{
        size_t sz;
        auto psize, cpuspeed, getMhz[] = {CTL_HW, HW_CPUSPEED};
        sz = sizeof(cpuspeed);
        sysctl(getMhz, 2, &cpuspeed, &sz, NULL, 0);
        printf("CPU: %d MHz Free: %ld MB\n", cpuspeed, (sysconf(_SC_AVPHYS_PAGES)*sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE))>>20
);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For free, use the [source](http://www.openbsd.org/anoncvs.html). CPU clock speed is trickier. `dmesg | grep CPU | grep Hz` will do it in a shell. You may want to try parsing your system log.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `popen` function. It creates a pipe, forks a given shell command, and returns a file descriptor you can read from.

```
man popen
```